# show data in outside textbox from selected row in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am having a grid view created by using template fields.  I inserted a link button using template fields in the grid view.
There are 4 textboxes outside the GridView.. i want to select the row on link button's click and  put the selected row's data in text boxes.  I am using a row command even for this but its not working ... the syntax i am using is .:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gview" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" onrowcommand="gview_RowCommand">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("book_name") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Author">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("book_author") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Publisher">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("book_Publisher") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Price">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("book_Price") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
<ItemTemplate>


<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDet" CommandName="cmdBind" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"  runat="server" CausesValidation="false">View Details</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>   

</Columns>
```

and Code behind file :

```
protected void gview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cmdBind")
    {
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(lb.CommandArgument);


        //Bind values in the text box of the pop up control
        txt_name.Text = gview.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
        txt_author.Text = gview.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
        txt_price.Text = gview.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: What's the error you are getting? You mean this is not working?

Comment: yes... its giving me an error .. something like... Object reference not set to an instance..

Answer (score 3):

I think this works:

```
protected void gview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e){
if (e.CommandName == "cmdBind")
{

    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);


    //Bind values in the text box of the pop up control
    txt_name.Text = gview.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
    txt_author.Text = gview.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
    txt_price.Text = gview.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempting it the way you are is not impossible, but it may be easier to just use the in built select buttons for each row.  That way you can just use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the gridview:

```
protected void gview_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_name.Text = gview.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    txt_author.Text = gview.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    txt_price.Text = gview.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
}
```